# Change the text of textbox through javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to change the value of textbox through javascript.

I have a user control from which I call a js file. There is a textbox in the usercontrol and then in the js file i pass that textbox value. After the button(it is in user control) is clicked, the js file does some operations. After the button is clicked and operations are over, i want to change the value of the textbox.

```
User control

a textbox and a button

 string submitArgs = String.Format("'{0}',tboxTimeMeasured.ClientID);
  JsSubmitValues.Value = "javascript:SubmitMeasure(" + submitArgs + ");";     


Js File: 
    function SubmitMeasure(control_TimeMeasured) {
//some operations
//and success= true        

if (success) {
            alert("Your changes have been saved successfully!");
            var datetimeNow = new Date();
            control_TimeMeasured.value = datetimeNow.getHours() + ":" + datetimeNow.getMinutes(); 
        }
    }
```

Here, it goes in the success loop, the control_TimeMeasured is the value of textbox which is passed from a user control to a 'js' file. How can I change the value of control_TimeMeasured ??

Comment: Its unclear exactly what you're asking. Perhaps you could try to explain exactly what the symptoms of the problem you are seeing are. Can you use the web browser development tools to debug what `control_TimeMeasured` is?

Answer (score 1):

If `control_TimeMeasured` is an ASP.NET textbox that's being rendered on the server side, chances are its runtime ID will be different than what you have specified. You can use the `<%= control_TimeMeasured.ClientID %>` syntax to get its runtime ID. You also want to **select** the control (using its ID) before you can change its properties; you have to do a little bit more than just referencing it by its name. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("<%= control_TimeMeasured.ClientID %>").value = 
       datetimeNow.getHours() + ":" + datetimeNow.getMinutes();
```

Alternatively, if you have `jQuery`, you can do this:

```
$("#<%= control_TimeMeasured.ClientID %>")[0].value =
       datetimeNow.getHours() + ":" + datetimeNow.getMinutes();
```

Now if `control_TimeMeasured` is just a normal `input` element, you can simply do this:

```
document.getElementById("control_TimeMeasured").value = 
           datetimeNow.getHours() + ":" + datetimeNow.getMinutes();
```

Comment: I tried first 2 options: 

Erron 1st: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Erron 2nd: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= control_TimeMeasured.ClientID %>

I cahnged the 2nd value to  $("#" + control_TimeMeasured.ClientID)[0].value = 'hi'; Then it is giving error as first one

Comment: I think there is no property as value, it is valueof.

Comment: Is there a control on your page with ID set to `control_TimeMeasured`? Can you post the exact value of `control_TimeMeasured`?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="tboxTimeMeasured"  runat="server" Width="100px" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: But the value which is passed from user control to js file is in control_TimeMeasured

Answer (score 0):

In your example `control_TimeMeasured` will be a string. To use this in javascript you will need to use the id to find the element like this.

**UPDATED:**

```
var element = document.getElementById(control_TimeMeasured);
if(element){
    if(element.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT'){
        var datetimeNow = new Date();
        element.value = datetimeNow.getHours() + ":" + datetimeNow.getMinutes();
    }else{
        console.error('element is not an input. Element is \'' + element.tagName + '\'.');
    }
}else{
    console.error('element with id\'' + control_TimeMeasured + '\' was not found.');
}
```

Comment: getting the error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I think there is no property as value, it is valueof.

Comment: In that case I imagine there is no element on the page with that id. I've updated the example to help you debug. if the element is not found the javascript will log the id to the console. Then you will be able to see what the ID is and if it matches with the id in the input tag.

Comment: @user1989 `value` is a property of the HTML input element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties

Comment: It does not go in the else loop. So there would be something in the element. But when i write 'element' and try for intellisense, it gives me option for valueof and not value

Comment: then I suspect the element is not an input element, Can you see the TagName property of element in your debugger?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="tboxTimeMeasured" runat="server" Width="100px" ></asp:TextBox>